# The name of a mathematical property

Tags: definition, normal-distribution, kalman-filter

When two Gaussian equations are multipled together, the outcome is another Gaussian distribution. Roger R. Labbe Jr., author of "Kalman and Bayesian Filters in Python" calls this property "rare" and points out that $sin(x) sin(y)$, for example, does not yield a $sin()$.

My question is simply, does that property have a name?

Comment: What do you mean "two Gaussian distributions are multiplied together"? Two Gaussian random variables or two Gaussian densities?

Comment: The exact quote is "The mathematics of the Kalman Flter is beautiful in part due to the Gaussian equation being so special. It is nonlinear, but when we add and multipy it using linear algebra we get another Gaussian equation as a result"

Comment: What do you call "Gaussian equation" ?

Comment: The author shouldn’t have used the word “equation” — this is a terrible red flag. All the author is saying is that the product of two exponentials (and in particular Gaussians) is again an exponential. In other words, the class of exponential functions (those of the form $e^{f(t)}$) is closed under multiplication.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would call it "closure under multiplication".

Comment: This is a comment, IMO.

Comment: @coffeemath while the answer is short, it is an answer. It is incomplete, though. Give evidence that this is standard nomenclature. For instance: "groups are closed under multiplication as a definition" cite that sort of language in literature.

Comment: user247327-- Re-reading OP's post I agree it asked only for a name of the property. I can delete comment if you want.